# cocos2d js - cannot load a frame of a spritesheet

Tags: loading, sprite-sheet, cocos2d-js

I have a game where I use spritesheet animations. Some images do load and some don't and I wonder why.

On those that don't, I'm getting:

`$  #image.png does not exist`

I use TexturePacker to create the images.

I've tried using smaller images, less images, less textures but I'm still unable to load certain images.
Could it be the names? I'm using pngs:

`brankar4-1.png
brankar4-2.png
brankar4-3.png`

EDIT: I use free TexturePacker (with free featues) for all of my sprites and it works for some images and for some it doesn't.

Comment: Are you using any pro features on texturePacker with Trial mode?

Comment: no, I'm using just the basic features

Comment: try without the hyphen in the name